# как удалить все символы между <@ и > js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

например, у меня есть строка: привет, <@122>. Мне нужно удалить все символы между <@ и >, включая сами <@ >, например:
`Было: Привет, <@123> Стало: Привет`,
Но если между <@ и > находится цифра 2, то удалять не нужно, например:
`Было: Привет, <@2> Стало: Привет, <@2>`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
'Привет <@2>'.replace(/<@.*>/g, (match) => match === '<@2>' ? match :'')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

написал такую регулярку:

```
/(\<@[\d]+(?<!@2)\>)/gim
```

Она ищет совпадение по следующему шаблону `<@[любое число, кроме 2]>`, при совпадении удаляется весь шаблон, через метод [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Тест:

```js
const str = `Привет, <@123>
Привет, <@2>
Привет, <@22>
Привет, <@22>Привет, <@22>
Привет, <@TEST>
Привет, <@12322>
Привет, <@ASD>
Привет, <ASD>`;

console.log(str.replace(/(\<@[\d]+(?<!@2)\>)/gim, ''));
```

Comment: спасибо большое!